# Tipo de mime para abrir un mapa

Tags: html, google-maps, web, mime

He tenido curiosidad por los enlaces en las paginas web que '*abren*' ciertas aplicaciones utilizando una especie de **mime** dentro de una etiqueta `<a href="mailto:correo@dominio.com">correo</a>`(es el más conocido), este habre el cliente de correo que tengamos instalado, si estamos viendo la web desde una PC abrirá Outlook (en Office con Windows, por ejemplo) o si es desde un móvil Android abrirá la aplicación de Gmail para poder enviar un email.

Tambien me sorprendió que con un `tel:12345` podría abrir el marcador de mi telefono directamente desde un movil, o si tengo la aplicacion de Skype desde el PC.

Busqué algunos ejemplos de otros casos:

```
mailto:contacto@dominio.com                          //para abrir el gestor de correo
tel:+5555555555                                      //para abrir el marcador de telefono
file:url                                             //para abrir un archivo local
magnet:?xt=urn:sha1:PDAQRAOQQRYS76MRZJ33LK4MMVZBDSCL //para abrir el cliente torrent
market://details?id=com.example.android              //para abrir Google Play 
whatsapp://send?text=Hola&phone=+555555              //para abrir Whatsapp
```

Mi pregunta, es: **¿Existe algún mime para abrir un mapa?** estaba pensando abrir directamente Google Maps (o Earth) desde un móvil o pc usando direcciones y coordenadas para un proyecto sobre lugares. También, me gustaría saber si existen otros tipos de este tipo de enlace. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Existe algún mime para abrir un mapa?

El esquema [`geo URI`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquema_geo_URI) definido como:

> un Identificador de Recurso Uniforme (`URI`) para las ubicaciones geográficas que utilizan el esquema de nombre 'geo'. Un geo URI identifica una ubicación física en un sistema de referencia de coordenadas de dos o tres dimensiones, de una forma compacta, simple, legible por humanos y siguiendo un protocolo independiente.

### Ejemplo:

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">Cuarteles generales de Wikimedia</a>
```

---

> También, me gustaría saber si existen otros tipos de este tipo de enlace

Te recomiendo leer [este articulo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)